# Get NoInitialContext Spring Boot 2.0.x Embedded Tomcat Resource and DataSource Configuration Using JavaConfig

Tags: spring, datasource, jndi, derby, embedded-tomcat

Following other links I have tried all configurations including enabling jndi of embedded tomcat container. (A very good detailed like is: https://www.roytuts.com/spring-boot-jndi-datasource/) But the problem is that the DataSource is looked up against JNDI and I get follwoing exception:

Please note that From Spring 2.0.x Embedded configuration classes have changed.

Get:
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial.

As for the question of JNDI lookup in Embedded tomcat is rare use case I am trying to simulate and reproduce a Database Connection Pooling Error in production and for that I have to use JavaConfig settings for Resource and DataSource both.